# Core search module, change markup

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-8, drupal-templates

I want to remove the *Search results* string added in the search page from line 119 of core/modules/search/src/Controller\SearchController.php.

```php
if (count($results)) {
  $build['search_results_title'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<h2>' . $this->t('Search results') . '</h2>',
  );
}
```

I am able to change the search form above and the result list using   preprocess_form function on the search form and preprocess_search_result on the search results.

Is there a preprocess function I missed, or can I use a custom  template file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to alter the route defined by the search module.
In order to do so:

1. Define in your `mymodule.services.yml` file following:

```
    services:
      mymodule.route_subscriber:
      class: Drupal\mymodule\Routing\RouteSubscriber
      tags:
        - { name: event_subscriber }
```

2. Create a class that extends the `RouteSubscriberBase` class on /mymodule/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php as following:

```
<?php
    /**
     * @file
     * Contains \Drupal\mymodule\Routing\RouteSubscriber.
     */
    
    namespace Drupal\mymodule\Routing;
    
    use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
    
    /**
     * Listens to the dynamic route events.
     */
    class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {
    
      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
        // Replace dynamically created "search.view_node_search" route's Controller
        // with our own.
        if ($route = $collection->get('search.view_node_search')) {
          $route->setDefault('_controller', '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleSearchController::view');
        }
      }
    }
```

3. Finally, the controller itself located on /mymodule/src/Controller/MyModuleSearchController.php

```
<?php
    namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;
    
    use Drupal\search\SearchPageInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Drupal\search\Controller\SearchController;
    
    /**
     * Override the Route controller for search.
     */
    class MyModuleSearchController extends SearchController {
    
      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      public function view(Request $request, SearchPageInterface $entity) {
        $build = parent::view($request, $entity);
        // Unset the Result title.
        if (isset($build['search_results_title'])) {
          unset($build['search_results_title']);
        }
    
        return $build;
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @hugronaphor works perfect.
I wanted my search results title to be "Search results for '(searchterm)'" instead of just "Search results" and steps described by @hugronaphor do exactly that.

In my view function I put this:

```
if (isset($build['search_results_title']) && isset($_GET['keys'])) {
   $build['search_results_title'] = ['#markup' => '<h2>' . t('Search results for') . ' "' . $_GET['keys'] . '"</h2>'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can override item-list--search-results.html.twig, and replace the title, here:

```
  {%- if title is not empty -%}
    <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  {%- endif -%}
```

Just remove that h3.

Comment: You are speaking about another template. The thread starter actually wants to know how to manipulate the search page controller's output. Because the render array with the key 'search_results_title' is simple markup and has no theme oder type key, one needs to manipulate the controller output directly.